# oauthd not asking me to set a user/pass on first use

Tags: oauth.io

I'm trying to figure out the **oauthd** system ( https://oauth.io/docs/oauthd) , so I can do social media authentication on my own server, rather than using theirs (which seems to go offline a fair bit for me)

Anyway, I've installed it, run `init` to create the instance, and then `start`, as per the below output:

```
oauthd start
Initializing plugins engine
Loading admin-auth
Loading slashme
Loading request
Loading front
oauthd start server
oauthd listening at http://:::6284 for https://example.com:6284
Server is ready (load time: 1.85s) Wed, 11 Mar 2015 17:20:24 GMT
```

Now, as per the document - I should go to:

http://example.com:6284/admin

...and its MEANT to ask you to setup a user/password, which will be the admin logins. Unfortunately, it doesn't do this. I just get sent to:

http://example.com:6284/login ... where it asks me to login with an email/password, both of which I don't have yet:

[image]

Can anyone explain what step I'm missing? I've love to get this going - as I'm not a fan of having to use 3rd party systems (i.e oauth.io), as you are at their mercy when it goes offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logging in for the first time actually creates your admin user with the entered credentials. So for example if you enter 'admin@yourmail.com' as the e-mail and 'letmepassplease' as the password, you'll be able to log in with these credentials in the future.

I can see why it's not clear, and we will probably improve this later. In the meantime you can create an issue about this on the Github repo.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: doh, can't believe I didn't just try that! Lets me in now :)

Comment: sorry to drag this one back up, but I'm stuck. How do you go about resetting the admin details?